# Is it possible to store,retrieve and remove the values in the keychain item using user defined keys in iOS?

Tags: ios

In an iOS Hybrid application, I want to store some sensitive information in the keychain item linke NSDictionary and few NSString values. Instead of using core constants, Is there any possibility to use user defined constants in keychain..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Save yourself the hassle, check out https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain

Comment: Yes but storing `NSDictionary` items is not what the keychain is designed for and it would need to be archived to data. For data you can use `NSArchiver` and save the resultant data using the `NSDataWritingOptions` such as `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` which will encrypt the data.